# Issue with splash screen and condition to launch one of two screen C#

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, splash-screen

I have a program that I am working on that will allow one to record inventory of items.  It is for my personal use at the moment.  Consists of four forms:

- SplashScreen
- CreateNewAccount
- LoginForm
- MainForm

The way I am TRYING to get this thing to work is when the user (me) starts the application for the first time it will load the splash screen on a 3 second timer.  Once the timer ends it will check the database\LOGIN table for number of rows.  If number of rows equals "0" then it will launch into the account creation form.  If it equals "1" it will launch into the LoginForm.  Rather than going to the CreateNewAccount form it goes to the login page. I have tried setting up an if statement (as can be seen in the splash screen form commented out) for it to look for the row count in the table but that was not working.

At this time it will launch into the login form because I have that one set as the form to launch on start. (Application.Run(new LoginForm()); Not sure what else to do....

**SPLASH SCREEN:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {


        InitializeComponent();


        //this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        //this.timer1.Interval = 2000;
        //this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);


    }

    private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        //SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login", con);
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //sda.Fill(dt);
        //if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "0")
        //{

        //    CreateNewAccount rf = new CreateNewAccount();
        //    rf.Show();

        //}
        //else
        //{

        //    LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
        //    lf.Show();
        //}
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            timer1.Stop();
        //this.Hide();


    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

**CreateNewAccount**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class CreateNewAccount : Form
{

    public CreateNewAccount()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
        lf.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //instance of sqlconnection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into LOGIN values('" + newUserName.Text + "','" + newPassword.Text + "','" + firstName.Text + "','" + lastName.Text + "','" + newEmail.Text + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\UPP");
        key.SetValue("Pass", newPassword.Text);


        if (i > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
            lf.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("New User Account added successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem creating the account.  Please check the values and try again.");
        }


    }

}
}
```

**LoginForm**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{



    //Method for the LoginForm
    public LoginForm()
    {
        //Creates thread for the Splash Screen
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        InitializeComponent();

        //Aborts the Thread for the Splash Screen
        t.Abort();
    }



    //Method for the Splash Screen
    public void SplashStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen());

    }

    //Method for the button to exit program
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }



    //Method to login when button is clicked
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username='" + userName.Text + "' and Password = '" + password.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Main wipd = new Main();
            wipd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check your username and password and try again.");
        }
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        CreateNewAccount na = new CreateNewAccount();
        na.Show();
    }

    private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

**MAIN**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Main : Form
{


    public Main()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: So is it throwing an error or what about it is not behaving the way you'd like?

Comment: Ill append this to the OP as well.  Rather than going to the CreateNewAccount form it goes to the login page.  I have tried setting up an if statement (as can be seen in the splash screen form commented out) for it to look for the row count in the table but that was not working.  tl;dr - It will not look for row count before launching the LonginForm or the CreateNewAccount form.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your dataadapter to see that it's filling the datatable correctly and to see what that value is?  Btw, on a side note, using dataadapters are arguably inefficient and using dataadapters for 1 value is shooting a mosquito w/ a shotgun